# Power BI Pro Content error

Tags: powerbi, gateway

I installed [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) in order to use SQL directly in my Dashboard. I published the report and found that none of my colleagues could view it without a Pro License. I tried everything but can't get rid of the so called "power BI pro content" in my dashboard.

So I uninstalled the gateway software and reinstalled Power BI.

I tested by creating a very basic report with one line chart linking to excel. Even this report can't be viewed by my colleagues because "it contains pro content".

As it turns out, ALL dashboards (even created by my colleagues) give this warning when I try to share it.

This is driving me nuts. Please can someone help.

thanks
g

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for what counts as Power BI Pro content is here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-power-bi-pro-content-what-is-it/

Some key tripping points: anything with a scheduled refresh that uses a gateway, or that refreshes more than daily counts as Pro. Anything posted to a group workspace or shared via an organizational content pack count as Pro too.

Bear in mind that a dashboard only needs one tile from a "Pro" report to be considered Pro.

In an enterprise setting, where your data is coming from SQL on-premises, it'd be hard to avoid pro content. Your data would have to be imported into Power BI Desktop, and refreshed & republished manually. You couldn't use direct query mode, a gateway, automatic refresh, group workspaces, or organizational content packs.

It's hard to comment specifically on why your very basic Excel report contains pro content. If you're sure it doesn't meet any of the documented reasons, click the Smile at the top-right of PowerBI.com and Submit an Issue. Microsoft should be able to tell you.

[image: Submit an issue]

*Note: What makes content pro could easily change in the future, so although I highlighted some common tripping points, I do recommend referring to the linked documentation for the definitive answer.*